# How to run a script if image file does not exist with mod_rewrite

Tags: image, apache, caching, mod-rewrite

I'm slamming my head against the keyboard trying to figure this one out. I am running a very image intensive site where I pre-process images (re-size / stamp / save) before showing the image.

Here is my question how to check if processed image already exists in directory (/cache/photos/600x500/xxx.jpg or /cache/photos/200x400/xxx.jpg) with mod_rewrite and if it doesn't how do I remap that request to a image processing script that will create the image from original and display it to the user.

Thank you for all your help. I've been trying to find a similar question but this is boggling my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#First check if the request is for a JPG:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*).jpg$

#If so, see if it exists in /cache/photos/600x500/xxx.jpg
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/photos/600x500/%1.jpg -f [NC]

#If so, serve that:
RewriteRule .* cache/photos/600x500/%1.jpg [L]

# Similar set of rules for other cache:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*).jpg$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/photos/200x400/%1.jpg -f [NC]
RewriteRule .* cache/photos/200x400/%1.jpg [L]

# Final rewrite for jpg files:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*).jpg$
RewriteRule (.*) createimage.php?image=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^(expression$)   /path/to/script?file=$1 [L]
```

And your script need to generate the file and print/serve the image